# How to extend array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6])

b = np.array([[7, 8],
              [9, 10]])
```

I want to extend array with expected result:

```
c = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 7, 8],
              [4, 5, 6, 9, 10])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [.hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
import numpy as np
 
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]])
 
b = np.array([[7, 8],
              [9, 10]])
 
c = np.hstack((a, b))
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  7  8]
 [ 4  5  6  9 10]]
```